# Move view up when keyboard is presented

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

***The Question:***

I have a `ViewController` that has a subclass with a `UIScrollView` in it.

In the scrollView there are 3 `UITextField`s. 2 of them with a numberPad keyboard and 1 with a `UIPickerView` keyboard.

The problem is that when the keyboards are presented, it hides the `UITextField`s. So what I'm trying to do is to move the `UIViewController`'s view up when the keyboards are being shown.

***What I've already tried:***

I've searched this question on SO and I've found some answers, based on them I've wrote this code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Keyboard notifications
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

//MARK: - keyboards

@objc fileprivate func keyboardWillShow(notification: Notification) {
    self.changeViewOriginBasedOnKeyboardPosition(notification: notification)
}

@objc fileprivate func keyboardWillHide(notification: Notification) {
    self.changeViewOriginBasedOnKeyboardPosition(notification: notification)
}

fileprivate func changeViewOriginBasedOnKeyboardPosition(notification: Notification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        let keyboardAnimationDuration = notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! TimeInterval
        UIView.animate(withDuration: keyboardAnimationDuration != 0 ? keyboardAnimationDuration : 0.2, animations: {
            if self.controllerContentView.frame.origin.y == 0  {
                self.controllerContentView.frame.origin.y = -keyboardSize.height
            } else {
                self.controllerContentView.frame.origin.y = 0
            }
        })
    }
}

fileprivate func dismissKeyboard() {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

//Touch handling

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.dismissKeyboard()
}
```

***The problem with what I've tried:***

Sometimes it works great, but sometimes the view "jumps" back up/"jumps" down and I can't understand why.

Does anybody see any problem with my code that can cause this bug?

Thank you!

Comment: please have a look this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40249707/3266248

Comment: You're setting the `frame` on the `controllerContentView` but if there's an AutoLayout update, those constraints will take over. Instead, change the constraints of `controllerContentView` and then call `view.setNeedsLayout()` inside a `UIView.animate` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a CocoaPod for this called IQKeyboardManager.

https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

It is dead simple to set up and works globally.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set height as per your keyboard hide. There is four observer for Keyboard available.

```
1) UIKeyboardWillShow
2) UIKeyboardDidShow
3) UIKeyboardWillHide
4) UIKeyboardDidHide
```

You need to register keyboard observer:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardShowNotification), name:NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardHideNotification), name:NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
```

Here is method observer method:

```
func keyboardShowNotification(notification:NSNotification){

    var userInfo = notification.userInfo!
    var keyboardFrame:CGRect = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    keyboardFrame = self.view.convert(keyboardFrame, from: nil)

    var contentInset:UIEdgeInsets = YOUR_SCROLLVIEW_OBJ.contentInset
    contentInset.bottom = keyboardFrame.size.height
    YOUR_SCROLLVIEW_OBJ.contentInset = contentInset
}

func keyboardHideNotification(notification:NSNotification){
    let contentInset:UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    YOUR_SCROLLVIEW_OBJ = contentInset
}
```

Another best key to handle keyboard is [IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager). You just have to add them to your application and it will handle everything.

Comment: You can use IQKeyboardManager. It will take care every thing about keybaord.